# Node.js async.queue doesn't work

Tags: node.js

I have this very simple program and the output should be "foo" and then "baz", but for some reason "baz" isn't printed on the screen. What mistake am I making?

```
var async = require('async');

var q = async.queue(function (task, callback) {
    console.log(task.message);
}, 1);

q.push({ message : "foo" }, function (err) {});
q.push({ message : "baz" }, function (err) {});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call `callback` in queue:

```
var q = async.queue(function (task, callback) {
    console.log(task.message);
    callback( );
}, 1);
```

This way it informs the queue, that it finished the task and the queue can jump to another one.

Answer (score 1):

You just forgott the

```
callback()
```

Try this it works for me:

```
var async = require('async');

var q = async.queue(function (task, callback) {
    console.log(task.message);
    callback();
}, 1);

q.push({ message : "foo" }, function (err) {});
q.push({ message : "baz" }, function (err) {});
```